# Webdriver.io: isExisting().then() is not a function

Tags: javascript, webdriver, webdriver-io

I would like to check if there is a logout element. If it is existing, I want to do the logout by clicking this element:

```
browser.isExisting('.logout').then(function() {
    browser.click('.logout');
});
```

But this gives me an `Uncaught TypeError: browser.isExisting(...).then is not a function`-error.

Comment: Is the purpose of your code is that you want to ensure that `.logout` exists before clicking on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using a version <4, you want this. http://webdriver.io/v3.4/api/utility/waitForExist.html

```
browser.waitForExist('.logout').then(function() {
    browser.click('.logout');
});
```

But if you use V4+, everything is synchronous ( http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/v4.html ), and you would need to rewrite a bit. http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForExist.html

Something like this

```
var logout = browser.element('.logout');
logout.waitForExist(5000);
browser.click('.logout');
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it to use object

```
browser.$('.logout').isExisting().then(function() {
   browser.click('.logout');
});
```

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/isExisting.html
You using 4.0 syntax for 5.0 webdriver.io

Check https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v500-2018-12-20 for more

Answer (score 0):

You can look here: http://webdriver.io/api/state/isExisting.html

```
client.isExisting(selector);
```

Returns boolean.
So your code should look something like this:

```
browser.isExisting('.logout').then(function(exist) {
    if (exist) {
        browser.click('.logout');
    }
});
```